# Getting timeout error with JMETER VERSION 5.21 Non HTTP ConnectException connection timeout failure

Tags: jmeter, ssl

I am simply trying to launch an application with JMETER 5.2.1 for **one user**. The webserver SSL certification was recently updated because the previous certification had expired. Prior to that JMETER had no problems launching the app.

Now I am getting the error:

```
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

When I go to the Chrome browser and enter the app ip I get that  `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. After accepting the risk The application opens.`

I have set the http request connect and response time values up to 8000. I have set the implementation to use HttpClient4.

I am wondering if I need to do something in the JMETER properties files in order to get the WEBSITE to accept JMeter now. I can get in via Chrome or Direfox. But JMETER fails(since the webserver ssl certification update).

Any advice to help me get JMETER running again would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably your website sever SSL certificate is invalid. Try with `http`(in previous if you have used https) from the browser if you can make successful request then the problem is with server `SSL` and also confirm whether this website host can be accessed from another machine

Answer (score 1):

1. [HttpHostException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/HttpHostConnectException.html) is a sub-type of [ConnectException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html?is-external=true) which:

   > Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port).
2. As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl):

   > **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

So I strongly doubt that this is due to the change of the SSL configuration of the server, most probably your host/port combination is not correct under [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

If you want more verbose information on what's going on under the hood you can add:

- `javax.net.debug=all` in *system.properties*
- `<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />` in *log4j2.xml*

Comment: thanks I will try this.